# Link to landing getting suscriber info

Tags: landing-page

When I receive a link going to my landing page, this URL has a "qs" param querystring... my question is: is it possible to get suscriber info (amscript or server-side js: key, and others user parameters) in first load (no form) landing?

I mean: is it possible to "write" email address (or user key or name) in the first load of my landing page?

I did not find that answer in documentation...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible using the following link in your email:

```
<a href="%%=v(MicrositeURL(xxxx)=%%">Link</a>
```

*xxxx is the ID of your Landing Page (viewed in the Landing Page properties area)*

If you would like to pass through additional parameters such as the jobID or listID you can use this

```
%%=v(MicrositeURL(xxxx,"jobid",[jobid],"listid",[listid]))=%%
```

Use the following code to retrieve the subscribers properties:

```
%%[
SET @FirstName = Firstname
SET @LastName = Lastname
]%%
```

*Assuming that the Firstname and Lastname profile attributes exist.*

In order to view these variables in the Landing Page use this anywhere outside of the AMPscript block.

```
%%=v(@FirstName)=%%
%%=v(@LastName)=%%
```

Once these AMPscript variables are set, you can place them into SSJS variables using the following code:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var JSFirstName = Variable.GetValue("@FirstName");
Write(JSFirstName) // Firstname value will be displayed here

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 

Is it possible to retrieve that data in js server script? How could I know all variables declared in a landing page?

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect your question.  All the variables from the Profile Attributes of your Marketing Cloud Account will be available for retrieval when using the following in your email <a href="%%=v(MicrositeURL(xxxx)=%%">Link</a>

Comment: No problem, I wish I had these answers 2 years ago when I started working with Landing Pages in Marketing Cloud!